# webpack: how to transpile code in node_modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I want to import [nano-memoize](https://github.com/anywhichway/nano-memoize) in my web application that uses Typescript and Webpack to transpile to ES5.

- `npm install nano-memoize`
- add `import 'nano-memoize/browser/nano-memoize'` to the source file.

These steps do not work in IE 11. The page simply doesn't load.

On inspecting the code for nano-memoize/browser/nano-memoize.js in IE 11 developer console, I noticed it uses arrow function. If I copy nano-memoize/browser/nano-memoize.js directly to my source folder, they get transpiled to ES5 and everything works in IE 11 too.

So why is nano-memoize/browser/nano-memoize.js not getting transpiled?

Build setup:

```
webpack                   : ^4.40.2,
@babel/core               : ^7.4.0,
awesome-typescript-loader : ^5.2.1,
```

**UPDATE**:
This was a webpack configuration issue where the node_modules are excluded from compilation. The skeleton setup is created by a script and my bad I never check this. The following in webpack.config.js for babel-loader can selectively compile the required node_modules. Replace  with required module name.

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: function(modulePath) {
    return /node_modules/.test(modulePath) &&
        !/node_modules\/<MY_MODULE>/.test(modulePath);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try it by using polyfills in your project , Below is the script tag to import in your index.html file 
 `<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Doesn't work. The issue is arrow function for which polyfill doesn't work.

Comment: Go through this article for webpack config https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-babel-webpack/